# How is it possible to control false discovery rate (FDR) without knowing the power and the prevalence of the nulls?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, false-discovery-rate

If we have p-value 0.05, to calculate probability of our discovery to be false positive, we need to use complex formula with prevalence (prior probability) and statistical power.

If we have lots of p-values, we magically don't need to deal with prevalence/power anymore and can just apply some Benjamini or others correction. And it will control FDR at 0.05 level (on average, if we repeat same experiment infinite amount of times).

I can not merge these 2 facts in my head. If we have only 2 p-values, will the trick with FDR work (obviously no) and where is the border? Do we need to take prevalence into account for multiple testing correction (my simulations and theory shows that kind of no if we don't take degenerative cases such as "almost all our data comes from null" into account - FDR there is either ~0% or ~100%), but how come?

Comment: +1 Excellent question.

Comment: In such small samples I would Bonferroni the life out of the thing. (I agree with @amoeba though, good question)

Comment: but hey, as far as I know, Bonferroni is equal to (new_alpha = alpha / number_of_tests) threshold decrease. So we reduce error rate to this value. And in theory we should again switch to (1-Prevalence) * new_alpha / (Prevalence * Power + (1 - Prevalence) * new_alpha) for each test we've done. Am I missing something here?

Comment: obviously there is a mess with "individual test FDR" and "bulk FDR", so may be it would be honest to introduce "FDR with prevalence and power" for each test, but nowdays everybody reports just q-values (while q-value of 0.01 means different for tests of different power - this is for sure) and everybody is satisfied with it, and why these 2 additional components such as prior/power disappear for bulk solution - that's beyond my knowledge. Law of large something?

Comment: (1) My intuition is that if one has a lot of p-values, then their distribution allows to estimate the power / prevalence of the nulls. E.g. imagine that the distribution is uniform from 0 to 1. Then you can conclude that either the prevalence of nulls is ~100% or your power is ~0%. You cannot do it if you only have 1 or 2 p-values, you need a lot. [cont.]

Comment: (2) However, nothing in the BH procedure requires having a lot of p-values. So it should be mathematically valid even for 1 single p-value. But applying BH adjustment to 1 p-value amounts to doing nothing. Look carefully into the BH paper to understand how come FDR is still controlled. CC @usεr11852.

Comment: (1) looks like a valid point for me unless there are tests of different power and prevalence. what becomes then - no idea. for sure all p-values from small power tests will be wiped out which has nothing to do with FDR - so is that estimation of power/prevalence good for biggest power/prevalence tests only? if so, can power of discovery be improved after "separating" tests of obviously different power?

Comment: Power is irrelevant in the FDR setting, since you are controlling the rate of *false* discoveries, which are, under the null hypothesis, the only type of discoveries you will see.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood, but according to e.g. this paper https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphy.2016.00006/full#h3 - power is required to calculate FDR as a proportion of false discoveries to the overall amount of discoveries, but power is irrelevant in "rate of errors" setting (which p-value is).